# Order of $f(n) = \sqrt[\log n]{n} \cdot n^{\sqrt[\log n]{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

This is as far as i've gone:
$$f(n) = \sqrt[\log n]{n} \cdot n^{\sqrt[\log n]{n}} \iff f(n)^{1 / \sqrt[\log n]{n}} = (\sqrt[\log n]{n})^{1 / \sqrt[\log n]{n} } \cdot n \iff f(n) = n^{\sqrt[\log n]{n}}  $$

since $ \lim \limits_{x\to \infty} \sqrt[x]{x} = 1$

Now i haven't been able to proceed from there. If i divide $f(n)$ by $\sqrt[\log n]{n}$ i will prove that it's $\mathcal{O}\left(\sqrt[\log n]{n}\right)$ but i think i need to do better than that.. Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\sqrt[\log n]{n} = n^{1/\log(n)} = \left(e^{\log(n)}\right)^{1/\log(n)} = e
$$
So overall you have $f(n) = e \cdot n^e$

Comment: Your answers have helped me grow in strength and in wisdom.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
\log\left(\sqrt[\log n]{n}\right) = \log\left(n^{1 / \log n}\right) = 1
$$

Answer (score 2):

One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
f(n) = \sqrt[\log n]{n} \cdot n^{\sqrt[\log n]{n}}=n^{\large \frac1{\log n}}\cdot n^{\large n^{\frac1{\log n}}}=e^{\large \frac{\log n}{\log n}}n^{\large e^{\frac{\log n}{\log n}}}=e \cdot n^{\large e^1}\sim e \cdot n^{e}.
$$

Comment: $f(n) = e \cdot n^e$ is true for all $n$ right?

Comment: @stud_iisc $f(n)$ is meaningless for $n=0$ and for $n=1$. As the OP asked for *an order of* $f(n)$, I've then considered that $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Yes I understand that the order of $f(n)$ is what we need to find. And yeah $f(n)$ in it's original form is meaningless for $n=0$ or $1$. I just wanted to say, shouldn't the fifth **similarity** be just an **equality**? Otherwise the answer is sound.

Comment: @stud_iisc You are right! I do understand what you mean now :)